# get json from a post request to a nodejs server

Tags: json, node.js

Where in the request object is the json?

For example I know I can use body-parser to do this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json({ message: 'goodbye'})
})
```

And start my server and hit it with

```
curl -H "Cont/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz"}' http://localhost:3000/
```

but is there a way to do it without the body parser includes?  Can I just see the json in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it through [`node stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) as below

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var body = "";
    req.on("data", function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    req.on("end", function() {
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        res.json({ message: 'goodbye'})
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can

`//pipe to any writable stream
req.pipe(process.stdout);`

Sure if u want - u may save it to string using something like this

```
  var tmpstr = "";
  req.on("data", function (data) {
    tmpstr += data;
  });
  req.on("end", function() {
   //do stuff
   console.log("\ndata length is: %d", tmpstr.length);
  });
```